# Conversion failed when converting the nvarchar value '0.7' to data type int

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to divide 2 fields, one is nvarchar and the other is decimal. All the data in the nvarchar field is numeric but for some reason the db formatted this field as nvarchar. I am trying to convert/cast but since the data in the nvarchar field contains numbers with decimal points, the conversion does not work. Any help? Thanks

```
 select netweight, commercialsize1, case when CommercialSize1=0 then NetWeight else netweight/cast(commercialsize1 as decimal(18,2)) end as BatteryNetWeight
from dbo.part
order by CommercialSize1
```

Comment: Because `0.7` isn't an integer, it's a floating point number.

Comment: Why are you converting to a STRING for division?  Your query logic does not make sense.  Sample data and desired results might help.

Comment: A **`varchar`** representing a numerical value that isn't an integer cannot be converted to an `int`. Why are you storing numerical data as a `varchar` at all though?

Comment: sorry i posted the wrong code... nonetheless I get the same error using:

Comment: If you posted the wrong code, correct your question. We can't help you if we don't have the SQL you're actually using.

Comment: done, i arranged the code above, but had already posted it below thanks

Comment: Error is still clear. Appears that `commercialsize1` is a `varchar`; and we've already discussed the problems there.

Comment: what do you mean? CommercialSize1 IS nvarchar, but in my code I am clearing converting it to decimal and I get an error when trying to divide.

Comment: Unfortunately this is how the ERP was designed and now the data has been entered into this field which is nvarchar. Is there a workaround I could use?

Comment: What might be happening is a mix of two datatypes within the output as a result of the case statement.  You can't have two different datatypes in the same column of output.  Try converting both numerator and denominator in all cases.

Comment: You are stuck with a design that stores numbers as strings you may have some values that are not actual numbers. And then when you try to do math it is going to fail because it first has to convert every value in the table to the numeric datatype. And when it encounters invalid values it will fail. Add to that you are mixing datatypes in your case expression and this has issues all over the place.

Comment: You're only casting CommercialSize1 in one place, the other is doing implicit conversion: `when CommercialSize1=0`.